# i have new in ios how to prepare and install build on diawi

Tags: objective-c

I have an application on App Store with 5.9 build version.But he wants to install it on the above of App store build. I changed my build version from 1.92 to 1.9 and gave him Diawi link . Now he is unable to install Both 1.9 and 1.92 This issue is coming only in iOS 8 and above. I can install the Diawi link to ios 7 and its working perfectly.

```
Advance th@nx for helping me....
```

Comment: hello mr.aman please  share some screen shot if possible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling **TestFlight** in your iTunes and share the app with the version you need. I'd recommend you to use **Fabric**(crashlytics) which takes care of maintaining all the shared app's builds and crash reporting.